# How to get the text field blank? What's wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<INPUT type="text"  name="q"  />
<INPUT type="button" value="submit" onclick=" q.value='';"/><br/>
<div style="width:50em; height:33em;border:2px black solid;overflow:auto">
    <div id='target'> </div>
</div>
```

I want to free up the text field q

Comment: Check console for errors!

Comment: Use `id` instead of `name`...`<INPUT type="text" id="q" />`.. `ID` properties are global variables ;)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/p05gcv6c/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="q.value='';" />
<br/>
<div style="width:50em; height:33em;border:2px black solid;overflow:auto">
  <div id='target'> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tag name of your first input tag is "input", not q. "q" is a value of the name attribute in this tag. Probably it would be a better idea to use id instead of the name attribute, but in the case of using the name attribute, use this code in your onclick function:

```
document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value=''
```

Note that getElementsByName("q") returns all tags that have the name attribute value equal to "q".